# Ubuntu 16.04 Login loop with NVIDIA GTX 980

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm, gdm

I have a desktop PC with an NVIDIA GTX 980 and an inbuilt graphics driver as well (Matrox) in the Intel Motherboard.
I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04, Kubuntu 16 and Ubuntu Server 16.04 but I'm having some problems associated with my graphics card. Various problems I faced while installing the NVIDIA drivers:

- The display is blank
- The display flickers
- Items on the screen do not display correctly or very slow moving
- The computer boots to low-graphics mode
- An error saying "Oh no! Something has gone wrong!"

Your specific issue may not be here, but try the solutions described in the answers anyway.

If my answer didn't work for you or if you have a better way, feel free to post another answer, describing your problem and how you fixed it.